# matplotlib hooking in to save_figure button events

Tags: matplotlib, events, button, backend

Does anyone know how to get the 'save figure' button events from a matplotlib figure?

I need the events to call some of my functions when this button is pressed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_bases import NavigationToolbar2

save_figure = NavigationToolbar2.save_figure

def new_save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  print( 'save_event')
  # save_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)

NavigationToolbar2.save_figure = new_save


fig = plt.figure()
plt.text(0.35, 0.5, 'Hello world!', dict(size=30))
plt.show()
```

But if i press `save figure` it doesn't call my function `new_save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2` [does not implement](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a45712e1c909949e4910225614fd1dd49c10c148/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2941) a `save_figure` method. This method is implemented in each of the backends specifically. E.g. for the Qt5Agg backend this is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a45712e1c909949e4910225614fd1dd49c10c148/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L813). Hence you need to monkey-patch the respective method of the actual backend in use. 
For the Qt5Agg backend this might look like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT

save_figure = NavigationToolbar2QT.save_figure

def new_save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  print('save_event')
  save_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)

NavigationToolbar2QT.save_figure = new_save

fig = plt.figure()
plt.text(0.35, 0.5, 'Hello world!', dict(size=30))
plt.show()
```